# Issue with dialog box using AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-support-library

When I switch from Activity to AppCompatActivity in Android development, the dialog box seems to have a UI issue.

Here's how the dialog buttons look like using Activity:

[image]

Here's how the dialog buttons look like using AppCompatActivity:

[image]

Crop Photo is the Positive button, Full Photo is the neutral button, and the cancel buttons looks out of place. Can this be fixed or do I overlook anything?

I have also tried using import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog or the default android AlertDialog, both result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how *material design* works. The affirmative action (the positive button) is always placed on the right, then on the left of it is the dismissive action.

Technically the [guideline](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html) says that *"Dialogs should not include more than two actions."*, but it is fine if it doesn't leave the dialog in an *indeterminate state*. However, you may want to create your own dialog layout with a list instead of relying simply on the action buttons if you think the look-and-feel is bad.